# Dynamically display the records of database in window forms

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I would like to display the records of my database on the windows form.
The thing is that windows form should display whenever there is a change inside the database.

For example, if there is a new record in the database, the windows form will automatically show that new record in the datagrid view.

Any ideas or ways to implement this simply? A brief idea will do. I will research and implement more on that.

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Great! It is useful. May I know it can also be done with oracle database?

Comment: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/database-change-notification-in-oracle.html